# Manage music from cloud to small mp3 player via ubuntu

Tags: dropbox, mp3

Two goals I wish to accomplish with a small-ish mp3 player (~8GB):

(1) Store music files (~80GB) in Dropbox only to free space in my laptop's HD. Is it possible to keep an up-to-date index of cloud music files in my laptop?

(2) Copy/replace subsets of songs to save in the mp3 player every once in a while. What software will ease this management from my laptop? ([This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196239/how-to-get-music-from-dropbox-to-any-mp3-music-type-app) suggests software that seems unavailable for linux.)

Your general and specific advice is much appreciated.

My laptop runs on ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

Thank you!

Comment: You may keep the data in the cloud (Dropbox) and not install the sync client but no "index". Or install the sync client and do a full or selective sync but them you'll end up with the files in your drive as well. And any generic MP3 players (like the one you got from 2008), unlike iPODs, work as a mass storage device (like any other USB stick) so you can use any file manager to save/delete files on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to implementing part 1 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/906286/uploading-large-folders-to-dropbox-from-external-hard-drive/906313#906313). The trick is to keep large files in an external drive, sync to dropbox via simlink, then do selective-sync to exclude that directory while keeping contents in the cloud only.

I still have no clue about indexing contents in the HD. [Dropbox-pro offers [smart-sync](https://www.dropbox.com/smartsync) to accomplish this, but no linux distro so far :( ].

One idea is to *include* the directory in selective sync but then *exclude* all its sub-directories. Thus, using `dropbox exclude` from the [Linux console](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/linux-commands) should list every sub-directory excluded. Not exactly an index, but pretty close for music arranged by artist.

As a plus, `dropbox exclude remove <subdir>` will sync one such subdirectory for saving in the mp3 player via the laptop. Then `dropbox exclude add <subdir>` reverts.